# Checking if column contains meaningful data in SQL Server

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2005

I have a SQL Server 2005 table which contains several columns which I need to check if they have data using

```
case when MyColumn <> ''  then 1 else 0 END
```

My problem is that I need something to work on all datatypes, as the above wouldn't work on 0 values

example

```
case when MyColumn <> ''  then 1 else 0 END
```

will return false if the value is 0, which I require otherwise.

I tried to `trim`, `convert`, `cast`, using `len` and `datalength` to no avail.

Anyone have any suggestion please?

Comment: PS: I am new to MSSQL/T-SQL but necessity forced to me to use this db/language

Comment: `case when MyColumn <> '' or MyColumn <> 0 or MyColumn IS NOT NULL  then 1 else 0 END`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put check for 0 and null as well. some thing like:

```
case when MyColumn <> '' or MyColumn <>'0' Or MyColumn IS NOT NULL or MyColumn <>0 then 1 else 0 END
```